# Using async/await instead of callback when using Worklet

Tags: javascript, async-await, web-worker

I'm writing a wrapper class hiding the internals of working with `AudioWorklet`. Working with a worklet involves communication between a node and a processor through message ports.

As soon as the code running in the node reaches `port.postMessage()`, script execution in the node ends. When `node.port.onmessage` fires (through `processor.port.postMessage`), code in the node can resume execution.

I can get it to work by using a callback function. See the code below.

```js
class HelloWorklet {
    constructor(audioContext) {
        audioContext.audioWorklet.addModule('helloprocessor.js').then(() => {
            this.awNode = new AudioWorkletNode(audioContext, 'hello-processor');
            this.awNode.port.onmessage = (event) => {
                switch (event.data.action) {
                case 'response message':
                    this.respondMessage(event.data);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    requestMessage = (callback) => {
        this.awNode.port.postMessage({action: 'request message'});
        this.callback = callback;
    }
    respondMessage = (data) => {
        // some time consuming processing
        let msg = data.msg + '!';
        this.callback(msg);
    }
}

let audioCtx = new AudioContext();
let helloNode = new HelloWorklet(audioCtx);

const showMessage = (msg) => {
    // additional processing
    console.log(msg);
}

const requestMessage = () => {
    helloNode.requestMessage(showMessage);
}
```

and the processor

```
class HelloProcessor extends AudioWorkletProcessor {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.port.onmessage = (event) => {
            switch (event.data.action) {
            case 'request message':
                this.port.postMessage({action: 'response message', msg: 'Hello world'});
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    process(inputs, outputs, parameters) {
        // required method, but irrelevant for this question
        return true;
    }
}
registerProcessor('hello-processor', HelloProcessor);
```

Calling `requestMessage()` causes `Hello world!` to be printed in the console. As using callbacks sometimes decreases the readability of the code, i'd like to rewrite the code using `await` like so:

```
async requestMessage = () => {
    let msg = await helloNode.requestMessage;
    // additional processing
    console.log(msg);
}
```

Trying to rewrite the `HelloWorklet.requestMessage` I cannot figure out how to glue the `resolve` of the `Promise` to the `this.awNode.port.onmessage`. To me it appears as if the interruption of the code between `this.awNode.port.postMessage` and `this.awNode.port.onmessage` goes beyond a-synchronicity.

As using the `AudioWorklet` already breaks any backwards compatibility, the latest ECMAScript features can be used.

**edit**

Thanks to part 3 of the answer of Khaled Osman I was able to rewrite the class as follows:

```js
class HelloWorklet {
    constructor(audioContext) {
        audioContext.audioWorklet.addModule('helloprocessor.js').then(() => {
            this.awNode = new AudioWorkletNode(audioContext, 'hello-processor');
            this.awNode.port.onmessage = (event) => {
                switch (event.data.action) {
                case 'response message':
                    this.respondMessage(event.data);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    requestMessage = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.resolve = resolve;
            this.reject = reject;
            this.awNode.port.postMessage({action: 'request message'});
        })
    }
    respondMessage = (data) => {
        // some time consuming processing
        let msg = data.msg + '!';
        this.resolve(msg);
    }
}

let audioCtx = new AudioContext();
let helloNode = new HelloWorklet(audioCtx);

async function requestMessage() {
    let msg = await helloNode.requestMessage();
    // additional processing
    console.log(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there're three things that might help you

1. Promises don't return multiple values, so something like request message can not be fired again once its fulfilled/resolved, so it won't be suitable to request/post multiple messages. For that you can use Observables or RxJS
2. You can use `util.promisify` to convert NodeJS callback style functions to promises like so

```js
const { readFile } = require('fs')
const { promisify } = require('util')
const readFilePromise = promisify(fs.readFile)

readFilePromise('test.txt').then(console.log)
```

or manually create wrapper functions that return promises around them that resolve/reject inside the callbacks.

3. For resolving a promise outside of the promise's block you can save the resolve/reject as variables and call them later like so

```js
class MyClass {
  requestSomething() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.resolve = resolve
      this.reject = reject
    })
  }

  onSomethingReturned(something) {
    this.resolve(something)
  }
}
```